# Android-Sd card

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have created sdcard.iso file.Then i have opened the adb shell and i gave ls -l..

I found that the sdcard system file is d--------- instead of dwrxwrxwrx ..

I have tried to push image file into sdcard using DDMS-->File Explorer.I tried to push the file I cant.

I shows cannot push the file:Its is read only file system..

I set the Target also as -sdcard

Please help me out..

Comment: have you started your emulator with the parameter to use your sdcard.iso?

Answer (score 0):

once you create the sdcard image, you can place it in the avd path, or you can use the following switch to tell the emulator to use it:

> -sdcard <filepath>
>
> By default, the emulator loads the SD card image that is stored with the active AVD (see the -avd startup option).
>
> Alternatively, you ca start the emulator with the -sdcard flag and specify the name and path of your image (relative to the current working directory)

To make an sdcard image, you use [mksdcard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#mksdcard).

> mksdcard 1024M sdcard.img